# What's the different between :method => :put and => :post + routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, put

Why did he use `:put` and how should I route it ?

The form:

```
<p>Sign Up</p>
<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => new_user_path, :method => :put do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

There is a `:put` at the end and as you can [see](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575551/User-Authentication-in-Ruby-on-Rails#TheAuthenticationRoutes37) he didn't show how to route the `:put`-method.

My route.rb looks like this:

```
Calendar::Application.routes.draw do
  root "welcome#index"

  get "user/change_pw"
  get "user/forgot_pw"
  get "user/new" => "user#new"
  get "user/sent_pw"
  get "user/sign_in" => "user#sign_in"
  get "user/signed_out" => "user#signed_out"
  get "welcome/index"

  post "user/sign_in" => "user#login"
  post "user/new" => "user#register"
end
```

If I click "Sign up" the following error appears:

> No route matches [PUT] "/user/new"

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "convention" the form code is incorrect.  For a new resource, you should be using `post` method and not `put` method.  Please see [Representational state transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Vocabulary_re-use_vs._its_arbitrary_extension%3a_HTTP_and_SOAP) for details on the different http methods.

As shown, you also already have `post "user/new" => "user#register"` route defined, so fix the view code by either removing the `:method => :put` as `form_for` defaults to `post`, or by replacing the method to `:post`.

```
<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => new_user_path do |f| %>
```

Comment: I changed it, but it still didnt work: `Missing template user/user_new, application/user_new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "../Calendar/app/views"`

Comment: Console shows that the error is in line 29, which is this one: `render :action => "user_new"` and this is the method:`def register
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.valid?
      @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = 'Die Anmeldung war erfolgreich.'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      render :action => "user_new"
    end
  end`

Comment: The solution is: `render :action => "new"`. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mistake.  Just change the form's `method` to `:post`.  `PUT` is usually used for updating data, not creating it.

Comment: It should also update a existing instanz/user. so I want to use put.